# > Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using the following class to make a direct call from my app.

URL: https://github.com/wumke/react-native-immediate-phone-call

It's not allowing me to call even I follow all above-mentioned steps.

Please see below error while I was trying to assemble my build.

```
Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
/Users/MQ/pinnacle/android/app/src/main/java/com/pinnacle/MainActivity.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
        RNImmediatePhoneCallPackage.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults); // very important event callback
                                   ^
  symbol:   method onRequestPermissionsResult(int,String[],int[])
  location: class RNImmediatePhoneCallPackage
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Want to make direct call from my react native app

```
import com.github.wumke.RNImmediatePhoneCall.RNImmediatePhoneCallPackage;

...

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

...

@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        RNImmediatePhoneCallPackage.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults); // very important event callback
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some linking issues in the library you've added. 
Re install the library and try manually linking them.